# Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision

Tags: matlab, nan

I have an equation to calculate. But the command window shows "Warning: Matrix is singular to working precision.". And the result of the calculation is NaN in the matrix.

```
lambda = 13.5e-9;
k = 2*pi/lambda;
r0 = 1e-3;
a = 10e-6; b = 10e-6;
beta = 6*pi/180; 
Lx = 300e-6; Ly = 300e-6; dx=1e-6; dy=1e-6;
x = -Lx/2:dx:Lx/2-dx; y = -Ly/2:dy:Ly/2-dy;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
p = X/r0; q = Y/r0;
I = (sinc(k*a*p)).^2*(sinc(k*b*cos(beta)*(q*cos(beta)-sin(beta)+sin(beta)*sqrt(1-p.^2+q.^2)))).^2;
```

with my sinc function,

```
function result = sinc(x)
    if x == 0
        result = 1;
    else
        result = sin(x)/x;
    end
end
```

I got NaN in the results I. I don't know What's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sinc` function takes *matrix* `x` as input. Your `x == 0` will not spot other zeroes beyond the first. Furthermore, even if there were no zeroes in your data, I believe this matrix division is not what you want your code to do.

I believe you want element-wise division, not a matrix operation: `sin(x) ./ x`. I would do it simply by:

```
result = sin(x) ./ x;
result(isnan(result)) = 1; % makes those nans arising from 0/0 to 1.
```

Comment: The warning is disappeared with the ' ./ ' . However, all values are still NaN.

Comment: @lighttn: you if statement is also incorrect, not vectorized. Look into “logical indexing”.

Comment: @lighttn Those two lines should be the whole content of the `sinc` function and it should work just fine - values that are nan are replaced by 1. Remaining values should be correct.

Answer (score 0):

If I use the for, I can make it now. I am still wondering why the use of meshgrid (that I did %{..., ...%} below the for) doesn't work.

```
lambda = 13.5e-9;
k = 2*pi/lambda;
r0 = 0.15;
a = 3e-6; b = 4e-6; % square sizes at object plane (x', y')
I0 = 1; % intensity at center (x=y=0)
beta = 30*pi/180; % rotation aroud x-axis

Lx = 10e-3; Ly = 10e-3; 
dx=13.5e-6; dy=13.5e-6;
x = -Lx/2:dx:Lx/2-dx; y = -Ly/2:dy:Ly/2-dy;
xx = size(x,2); yy = size(y,2);
I = zeros(xx,yy);
for i = 1:xx
    for j = 1:yy
        x = i*dx-Lx/2;
        y = j*dy-Ly/2;
        I(i,j) = I0*(sinc(k*a*(x/r0))).^2*(sinc(k*b*cos(beta)*((y/r0)*cos(beta)-sin(beta)+sin(beta)*sqrt(1-(x/r0).^2+(y/r0).^2)))).^2;
    end
end

%{
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
p = X/r0; q = Y/r0;
I(x",y")
I = I0*(sinc(k*a*p)).^2*(sinc(k*b*cos(beta)*(q*cos(beta)-sin(beta)+sin(beta)*sqrt(1-p.^2+q.^2)))).^2;
%}

figure(1)
imagesc(x,y,I)
axis()
colorbar()
```